# C4594 warning in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I wrote this code so I can understand more about c++ , I know that I get this warning because of the virtual inheritance in class B and class C is not virtual public inheritance ,and I know that this warning can go if I changed it .

but what I don't understand is : why my code works and why it wont get this warning if I only made this change --->   class C :virtual public A **and not made the change for both classes (C and B)    :**

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "A"; }
    A(const A&) { cout << "a"; }
};
class B : virtual A
{
public:
    B() { cout << "B"; }
    B(const B&) { cout << "b"; }
};
class C : virtual A
{
public:
    C() { cout << "C"; }
    C(const C&) { cout << "c"; }
};
class D :B, C
{
public:
    D() { cout << "D"; }
    D(const D&) { cout << "d"; }
};
int main()
{
    D d1;
    D d2(d1);
}
```

: warning C4594: class 'D' can never be instantiated - indirect virtual base class 'A' is inaccessible

: message : 'A' is a private base class of 'B'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `protected` instead of `public` would suffice...

Now assume your classes would *not* inherit virtually.

What now happens is that any instance of `B` incorporates its own instance of `A` as well as does any instance of `C`. Both `B` and `C` call `A`'s constructor already, an inheriting class `D` doesn't need to care for.

This changes if virtual inheritance is introduced: Now the task of constructing the sole instance of `A` is delegated to the most derived class, which is `D` in given case.

`D` now needs access to this common instance of `A` to be able to call it's constructor. This can occur via `B` *or (!)* via `C` – so it suffices if *at least one* of these provides at least `protected` access to that single instance – `C` in given case but could have been `B` as well.

Comment: I see , let assume that I only made that change for class C and  that in my main has this : D d1 ;     as I know the compiler will go to class D then to class B then to class C , why it wont sent a warning if it goes to class B then to class A (because its the base)  and it sees that A is private and it cant access it ?. I can understand your explanation  but wont it make sense that  :If i made the change for class B and not for C then the compiler wont send a warning(because it goes to B first) , and if made the change for C and not B then the compiler will warn me (because it visits B first)

Comment: @sallyaaa It visits `B` first, discovers that there's no access – but it knows it's *not yet done* so continues, then sees that `C` *does* provide access and is happy -> no warning. The warning itself is is misleading (not untypical for MSVC...), suggesting `B` would need to provide the access, which is not the case, though. For comparison GCC's message: `error: 'class A A::A' is inaccessible within this context`

Comment: yeah , that makes sense too , thanks ^-^